# Compilation problem with tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, matrices, tikz-matrix

As I said, I'm writing math books for school; one of them is about matrices and I have several problems with it.

It's a big code, so I'm trying to summarize it:

1. Problem with TikZ matrix:
   When I try to compile it something like

   ```
   \draw [<->, yl] (A-2-4.north) to [bend left] node [arrow style mul] {$+$} (B-2-4.north);
   ```

   using the `tikz` package and the following `tikz` libraries:

   ```
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,calc,arrows}
   \usetikzlibrary{intersections,through,backgrounds}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathmorphing}
   ```

   I get

   ```
   No shaped name A-2-4 is known. See the pgf package documentation for explanation
   ```
2. And when I try to compile this (using `\include{filename}`):

   ```
    \chapterimage{m2summary.pdf}
    \chapter{Respostas e soluções}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \section*{\textcolor{ocre}{1. Matrizes}}
    \subsection*{Exercícios de fixação}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
    \tiny{
    \item $\ds A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
    }
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
   ```

   it shows:

   `Missing $ inserted`. HOW? I tried to compile with no text, actually, with no math text, and it keeps showing that $ is missing. I really don't know what to do!

Sorry for making this long post, I just tried to be as complete as I can. And I use WinEdt 8, MikTeX 2.9 that I installed this week (February 2014).

Code of TIKZ pic:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(A)[matrix of math nodes, nodes={node style ge}, left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]}] at (0,0){
  a_{11}                         & a_{12}                         & \cdots & a_{1n}                         \\
  \node[node style sp] {a_{21}}; & \node[node style sp] {a_{22}}; & \cdots & \node[node style sp] {a_{2n}}; \\
  \vdots                         & \vdots                         & \ddots & \vdots                         \\
  a_{m1}                         & a_{m2}                         & \cdots & a_{mn}                         \\
};
\node [draw, above=10pt] at (A.north) {matriz $\color{ocre}A$};
\node [right=20pt] at (A.east) {$\color{ocre}+$};

\matrix(B)[matrix of math nodes, nodes={node style ge}, left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]}] at (6,0){
  b_{11}                         & b_{12}                         & \cdots & b_{1n}                         \\
  \node[node style sp] {b_{21}}; & \node[node style sp] {b_{22}}; & \cdots & \node[node style sp] {b_{2n}}; \\
  \vdots                         & \vdots                         & \ddots & \vdots                         \\
  b_{m1}                         & b_{m2}                         & \cdots & b_{mn}                         \\
};
\node [draw, above=10pt] at (B.north) {matriz $\color{ocre}B$};

\matrix(C)[matrix of math nodes, nodes={node style ge}, left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]}] at (6,-4.5){
  c_{11}                              & c_{12}                               & \cdots & c_{1n}                                \\
  \node[node style sp, ocre] {c_{21}}; & \node[node style sp, blue] {c_{22}}; & \cdots & \node[node style sp, yl] {c_{2n}}; \\
  \vdots                              & \vdots                               & \ddots & \vdots                                \\
  c_{m1}                              & c_{m2}                               & \cdots & c_{mn}                                \\
};
\node [draw, below=10pt] at (C.south) {matriz $\color{ocre}C=A+B$};

\node (a) [above=10pt] at (A-2-1.north) {};
\node (b) [above=10pt] at (C-2-1.north) {};

\draw [<->, yl] (A-2-4.north) to [bend left] node [arrow style mul] {$+$} (B-2-4.north);
\draw [->, yl] (B-2-4.south) to (C-2-4.north);

\draw [<->, blue] (A-2-2.north) to [bend left] node [arrow style mul] {$+$} (B-2-2.north);
\draw [->, blue] (B-2-2.south) to (C-2-2.north);

\draw [<->, ocre] (A-2-1.north) to [bend left] node [arrow style mul] {$+$} (B-2-1.north);
\draw [->, ocre] (B-2-1.south) to (C-2-1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: To resolve the tikz's problem you need to give the complete tikzpicture's environment

Comment: Also, what the error message says it less important than what line it was on at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answers only the TikZ question. For the other, I'd recommend reducing your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and asking a new question about that.)

Your problem is that you have a `matrix of math nodes`, but you're using `\node {}` in the cells. By default, when you have a `matrix of` (`math`) `nodes` TikZ prepends something like `\node [name=A-1-2] {` to the contents of the cell (and adds the closing `};` after), but *not* when you use `\node` or similar in a cell. Quoting the manual:

> Conceptually, this key adds `\node{` at the beginning and `};` at the
>   end of each cell and sets the `anchor` of the node to `base`.
>   Furthermore, it adds the option `name` option to each node, where the
>   name is set to
>   *matrix name - row number - column number*. For example, if the matrix has the name `my matrix`, then the node in the upper left cell will
>   get the name my `matrix-1-1`.
>
> [..]
>
> If your cell starts with a `\path` command or any command that expands
>   to `\path`, which includes `\draw`, `\node`, `\fill` and others, the
>   `\node{` startup code and the `};` code are suppressed.

To be able to pass options/styles to the nodes, write e.g.

```
|[my node style]| content of matrix cell
```

I.e. add vertical bars around the brackets containing the options, and place this at the beginning of the cell.

Complete code below. You didn't add the definition of your styles, so I defined them as empty styles.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
  node style ge/.style={},
  node style sp/.style={},
  yl/.style={},
  arrow style mul/.style={},
}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{204, 119, 34}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(A)[matrix of math nodes, nodes={node style ge}, left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]}] at (0,0){
  a_{11}                         & a_{12}                         & \cdots & a_{1n}                         \\
 | [node style sp]| a_{21} & |[node style sp]| a_{22} & \cdots & |[node style sp]| a_{2n} \\
  \vdots                         & \vdots                         & \ddots & \vdots                         \\
  a_{m1}                         & a_{m2}                         & \cdots & a_{mn}                         \\
};
\node [draw, above=10pt,font=\color{ocre}] at (A.north) {matriz $A$};
\node [right=20pt,font=\color{ocre}] at (A.east) {$+$};

\matrix(B)[matrix of math nodes, nodes={node style ge}, left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]}] at (6,0){
  b_{11}                         & b_{12}                         & \cdots & b_{1n}                         \\
  |[node style sp]| b_{21} & |[node style sp]| b_{22} & \cdots & |[node style sp]| b_{2n} \\
  \vdots                         & \vdots                         & \ddots & \vdots                         \\
  b_{m1}                         & b_{m2}                         & \cdots & b_{mn}                         \\
};
\node [draw, above=10pt,font=\color{ocre}] at (B.north) {matriz $B$};

\matrix(C)[matrix of math nodes, nodes={node style ge}, left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]}] at (6,-4.5){
  c_{11}                              & c_{12}                               & \cdots & c_{1n}                                \\
  |[node style sp,ocre]| c_{21} & |[node style sp, blue]| c_{22} & \cdots & |[node style sp, yl]| c_{2n} \\
  \vdots                              & \vdots                               & \ddots & \vdots                                \\
  c_{m1}                              & c_{m2}                               & \cdots & c_{mn}                                \\
};
\node [draw, below=10pt,font=\color{ocre}] at (C.south) {matriz $C=A+B$};

\node (a) [above=10pt] at (A-2-1.north) {};
\node (b) [above=10pt] at (C-2-1.north) {};

\draw [<->, yl] (A-2-4.north) to [bend left] node [arrow style mul] {$+$} (B-2-4.north);
\draw [->, yl] (B-2-4.south) to (C-2-4.north);

\draw [<->, blue] (A-2-2.north) to [bend left] node [arrow style mul] {$+$} (B-2-2.north);
\draw [->, blue] (B-2-2.south) to (C-2-2.north);

\draw [<->] (A-2-1.north) to [bend left] node [arrow style mul] {$+$} (B-2-1.north);
\draw [->] (B-2-1.south) to (C-2-1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not at home right now, but I try after, thanks anyway! :D