# Tried to draw a network protocol but always get error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to draw the following diagram in LaTeX

[image]

I reference the method from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/drawing-network-protocols):

I can successfully compile the code from above link, but when I attempted to draw more lines between A and B by modifying the number in the:

```
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm,-latex] (m-4-2.south west)--(m-4-2.south east);
\draw[shorten <=-1cm,shorten >=-1cm,-latex] (m-7-2.south east)--(m-7-2.south west);
```

I always got the error message said:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named m-5-2 is known.
```

Any solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The syntax `m-4-2` means: node in row 4 and column 2; if your matrix has no nodes in that cell, you get that error.

Comment: That error can also occur if you use `\node` inside a `matrix of nodes` (see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163319/compilation-problem-with-tikz-diagram/163571#163571). Is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\XLR#1{\xleftrightarrow[\rule{2cm}{0pt}]{#1}}% \rule defines the width
\def\XR#1{\xrightarrow[\rule{2cm}{0pt}]{#1}}
\def\XL#1{\xleftarrow[\rule{2cm}{0pt}]{#1}}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} c c c @{}}
A  &  & B \\
   & \XLR{\text{KE}} \\
\text{obtain }k,T^A_{\text{KE}} &  & \text{obtain }k,T^B_{\text{KE}} \\
K:= \text{PRF}(k,\text{"KE"})   &  & K:= \text{PRF}(k,\text{"KE"})   \\
K_\text{mac}:= \text{PRF}(k,\text{"MAC"})   &  & K_\text{mac}:= \text{PRF}(k,\text{"MAC"}) \\
   & \XR{r_A} \\
   & \XL{r_B} \\
\text{[...]}
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]