# Problem on matrix of nodes with complex nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I've defined a node style which contains a `path picture` consisting into an inner node:

```
cross/.style={circle, minimum size=1cm,
    draw=black!70, fill=white,
    path picture={%
        \node[cross out, draw, ultra thick, red, minimum size=5mm]{};}}
```

This style can be used inside a `node`:

```
\node[cross] {};
```

and can be used inside a `\matrix`:

```
\matrix[fill=black!20, xshift=2cm] (b) {%
     \node[cross]{}; & \node[cross]{};\\ 
     \node[cross]{}; & \node[cross]{};\\};
```

[image]

but it fails when used inside a `matrix of nodes` with `nodes=cross`.

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\pgfutil@g@addto@macro #1#2->\begingroup 
                                         \pgfutil@toks@ \expandafter {#1#2}\...
l.15 ...odes={cross}, nodes in empty cells] (c) {&
                                                   \\ & \\};
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Could you explain me what's wrong?

Note: I've read [Nodes and matrix of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183896/nodes-and-matrix-of-nodes) but I think it describes another kind of problem.

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    cross/.style={circle, minimum size=1cm,
        draw=black!70, fill=white,
        path picture={\node[cross out, draw, ultra thick, red, minimum size=5mm] {};}},
    ]

    % This works
    \node[cross] (a) {};

    %This works
    \matrix[fill=black!20, xshift=2cm] (b) {\node[cross]{}; & \node[cross]{};\\ \node[cross]{}; & \node[cross]{};\\};

    %This is wrong
    %\matrix[fill=black!20, xshift=6cm, matrix of nodes, nodes={cross}, nodes in empty cells] (c) {& \\ & \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is `nodes={cross}`: In `path picture` it will apply it again. So it causes infinite recursion of  nodes. better add `no cross` or anything that can clean up `nodes` in `path picture`

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you, I've never had thought about a recursion problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path picture={\node[every node/.style=,cross out, draw, ultra thick, red, minimum size=5mm] {};}},
```

[image]