# Aligning matrix of nodes with grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am trying to render a grid of stones using the code below, however when I remove the stone in `m-3-1`, the stones above and to the right of it (particularly `m-1-5`) will be off-center:

[image: aligned]  [image: misaligned]

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.geometric}
\newcommand\stone[0]{|[circle, shading=ball, ball color=black!80!white, minimum size=.8cm]|} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184068/45824
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             anchor=south west,
             column sep={1cm,between origins},
             row sep={1cm,between origins},
             nodes in empty cells,
            ]
{
        &        &        &        & \stone \\
        &        &        &        &        \\
 \stone &        &        &        &        \\
};
\draw[step=1cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (5,3);
\draw[thick,red,->] (m-1-1) -> (m-1-5);
\draw[thick,red,->] (m-1-5) -> (m-3-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I ensure all the stones are aligned correctly?

Comment: First: don't use `\tikzstyle`. Use `\tikzset` instead.

Comment: @JouleV thanks, I moved it into the `\newcommand` definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cause of issue

First, your "working" code doesn't even output the intended diagram: the circles are not aligned yet

[image]

Adding option `draw` to every nodes in the "not working" code gives us

[image]

which can explain the problem: your nodes are aligned correctly, but the matrix itself is not at the right place.

#### Solution

- Use `\tikzset`
- Add option `inner sep`
- Use `minimum size` option for nodes
- Use anchor `center` for the arrows (see more below)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{stone/.style={circle,shading=ball,ball color=black!80!white,minimum size=.8cm}}
\newcommand\stone{|[stone]|} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184068/45824
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             anchor=south west,
             column sep={1cm,between origins},
             row sep={1cm,between origins},
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes={minimum size=1cm},
             inner sep=0pt
            ]
{
        &        &        &        & \stone \\
        &        &        &        &        \\
        &        &        &        &        \\
};
\draw[step=1cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (5,3);
\draw[thick,red,->] (m-1-1.center) -> (m-1-5);
\draw[thick,red,->] (m-1-5) -> (m-3-5.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]