# Tikz matrix does not allow me to \draw line between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

If I want to put a line between nodes 1-1 and 2-2:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of math nodes, left delimiter=\lvert, right delimiter=\rvert,column sep=4pt,row sep=4pt]
{
   \draw (0,0) circle (5pt); & \fill (0,0) circle (2pt); & \fill (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
   \fill (0,0) circle (2pt); & \draw (0,0) circle (5pt); & \fill (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
   \fill (0,0) circle (2pt); & \fill (0,0) circle (2pt); & \draw (0,0) circle (5pt);\\
};
%\draw[thick,red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2);
```

\end{tikzpicture}

I get:

```
generic/fonts/otf/lmroman12-bold.luc)(load luc: /home/xan/.texlive/texmf-var/lua
tex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman12-bold.luc) [13] [14]
Capítol 1.
(compiling luc: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman12-italic.l
uc)(load luc: /home/xan/.texlive/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroma
n12-italic.luc)(compiling luc: /var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmr
oman10-bolditalic.luc)(load luc: /home/xan/.texlive/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gener
ic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-bolditalic.luc) [15](compiling luc: /var/lib/texmf/luatex
-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmsans10-bold.luc)(load luc: /home/xan/.texlive/texmf-v
ar/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmsans10-bold.luc)

! Package pgf Error: No shape named magic-1-1 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.100     \draw[thick,red,->] (magic-1-1)
                                        |- (magic-2-2);
?
```

Why?

If I supress the \draw line everything is OK.

Comment: Because when you use `\draw`, `\node`, `\path` etc. in a `matrix of math nodes`, the automatic naming is deactivated. Same sort of problem as in [Compilation problem with tikz diagram](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163571)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error is the problem described in [Compilation problem with tikz diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163319/compilation-problem-with-tikz-diagram/163571#163571). Here Is is an alternative approach using node styles to draw the dots and circles instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt,fill=black,circle},
  ring/.style={inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,draw,circle}]
\matrix (magic) [matrix of math nodes,
                 left delimiter=\lvert,
                 right delimiter=\rvert,
                 column sep=4pt,row sep=4pt]
{
|[ring]| & |[dot]| & |[dot]| \\
|[dot]| & |[ring]| & |[dot]| \\
|[dot]| & |[dot]| & |[ring]| \\
   };
\draw[thick,red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is *exactly* what activate the possibility to call (magic-1-1)?

Comment: @somenxavier When you have a `matrix of nodes` or `matrix of math nodes`, and you only put some text in a cell, and *not* `\path`, `\node` etc. So for example in `\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes] { a & \node{b}; \\ };` you will be able to use `(m-1-1)`, but not `(m-1-2)`.