# Issue referencing TikZ matrix nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

In one of my documents I used the [following template](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/matrix-multiplication/) to illustrate a matrix multiplication but nowadays I get the error that shapes like `A-2-1` are unknown. This is a known issue described in various questions because apparently some nodes get no names and `\chainin` fails or something like that. I was wondering how can I fix this issue in the specific example I have linked above to continue using the graphic.

Comment: I think this might be a bug related to [matrix of math nodes]. If you use a matrix of nodes and add $...$ to every entry (AAAAH!) it works fine.

Comment: I had no idea SE was running short of full stops ;).

Comment: @cfr What are you referring to?

Comment: Your first sentence is rather long. Some other kind of punctuation would also work. Full stops are just the simplest.

Comment: Same problem as described elsewhere (e.g.[Compilation problem with tikz diagram](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163571)). There are several occurrences of `\node [node style sp] {...}` or similar in the code, replace these with `|[node style sp]| ...` and it works.

Comment: Oops, forgot that my vote would close the question directly. If you disagree with the closing let me know.