# Draw a double arrowed line between node and path

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I achieve to draw a line (using double sided arrows) between a node and the middle of a path?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,shadows}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \tikzstyle{vertex_basic}=[rectangle,thick,top color=white,bottom color=black!20, minimum size=50pt,scale=1]
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[vertex_basic, draw=black!50]
    \tikzset{initial text={}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[,>=stealth,ultra thick,black!50,text=black, scale=1.8,graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners},every new ->/.style={shorten >=1pt},auto]
    \matrix[row sep=20mm,column sep=2mm] {
        \node (X) [vertex,align=center] {X}; & & \node (Y) [vertex,align=center] {Y}; \\
        & \node (O) [vertex,align=center] {Outcome}; &\\
    };
    \path[<->] (X) edge node[align=center] {} (O);
    \path[<->] (Y) edge[densely dotted] node[align=left] {} (O);
    \path[<->] (X) edge[densely dotted] node[align=left] {} (Y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above coded produces the following image (without the red line). 
[image: Desired result]

How would it be possible to add a line using the style of the other lines at position of the red line? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've placed an empty node midway along the arrow from `O` to `X`, give it a name and you can draw a line to it. But if you don't use that node for anything, replace it with a `coordinate` as in

```
\path[<->] (X) edge coordinate (m)  (O);
```

Then you can draw the arrow you want with

```
\draw [<->] (m) -- (Y);
```

In the code below I suggest some other changes as well.

`\tikzstyle` is considered deprecated, so I moved the style definition into a `\tikzset`, cf. [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)

To the matrix I added the `matrix of nodes` option, which requires the `matrix` library, and `nodes={vertex}` to set the `vertex` style for all the nodes in the matrix.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} % <-- added 
\tikzset{
   vertex_basic/.style={
       rectangle,thick,
       top color=white,
       bottom color=black!20,
       minimum size=50pt},
  vertex/.style={vertex_basic, draw=black!50, align=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=stealth,
  ultra thick,
  black!50,
  text=black,
  scale=1.8
]

\matrix[
  row sep=20mm,column sep=2mm,
  matrix of nodes,nodes={vertex}
]
{
  |[alias=X]| X &                      & |[alias=Y]| Y \\
                & |[alias=O]| Outcome                  \\
};

\draw[<->]     (X) --coordinate(m) (O);
\draw[<->, densely dotted]     (Y) -- (O);
\draw[<->, densely dotted]     (X) -- (Y);
\draw[<->,red] (m) -- (Y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks completely different from what I did before, producing the same result :-) Would you mind to explain it further, especially using \draw instead of \path or the [alias=X]  notation?

Comment: @Robin `\draw` (short for `\path[draw]`) is used because I used `--` instead of `edge`, `\path (a) -- (b);` will create the path, but not draw it. The `edge` operation works a bit differently, see chapter 17.12 in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163571/ for an explanation of how a `matrix of nodes` work. `alias` is just a way of giving an additional name to a node. E.g. with `\node [alias=a] (b) {foo};` you can use either `\draw (a) -- ..` or `\draw (b) -- ..`.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

[image]

The trick is to use the tizlibrary `calc` to draw from `(X)!0.5!(O)` to `(Y)`. That is, from half way between `(X)` and `(O)` to `(Y)`.

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,shadows,calc}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \tikzstyle{vertex_basic}=[rectangle,thick,top color=white,bottom color=black!20, minimum size=50pt,scale=1]
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[vertex_basic, draw=black!50]
    \tikzset{initial text={}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[,>=stealth,ultra thick,black!50,text=black, scale=1.8,graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners},every new ->/.style={shorten >=1pt},auto]
    \matrix[row sep=20mm,column sep=2mm] {
        \node (X) [vertex,align=center] {X}; & & \node (Y) [vertex,align=center] {Y}; \\
        & \node (O) [vertex,align=center] {Outcome}; &\\
    };
    \path[<->] (X) edge node[align=center] {} (O);
    \path[<->] (Y) edge[densely dotted] node[align=left] {} (O);
    \path[<->] (X) edge[densely dotted] node[align=left] {} (Y);
    \draw[<->, red, very thick] ($ (X)!0.5!(O) $) -- (Y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to draw to the south west corner of `Y` then you can of course use

```
\draw[<->, red, very thick] ($ (X)!0.5!(O) $) -- (Y.south west);
```

to produce:

[image]